# VLC player embed code not working in ie.

Tags: embed, vlc

I implemented the following code in html file for embedding vlc player in my website but not working in ie8+ .

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
width="640" height="480" id="vlc" events="True">
    <param name="Src" value="test.3gp" />
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
    <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
    <param name="AutoPlay" value="False" />
 </OBJECT>
```

This code i found from http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX/HTML

please help. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157210/cross-browser-embed-vlc-plugin

Answer (score 2):

This is because

http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab

doesn't exist